# pyinstaller: matplotlib font cache changes to /var/folders in generated app

Tags: python, macos, caching, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I'm running pyinstaller 3.3.dev0+gb78bfe5 (which is current as of this writing) and seeing something strange: when I run the one-directory version of my app, I get a warning that matplotlib is rebuilding the font cache, but not when I run the app directly in python.

By printing mpl.get_cachedir(), I see that the pyinstaller-built version sees the cache dir in /var/folders/.... (the basename of which changes each run) rather than in ~/.matplotlib. Obviously a cache whose path changes on each isn't a very helpful optimization...

When I run the app directly in python, the cache dir is ~/.matplotlib. If I remove the cache, the first time I run the app (directly via python), I get the message and then no more on subsequent runs, as expected.

I see that TMPDIR is (automatically, apparently) set to /var/folders/9t/31_qw25565vdmzbtdsdlnh340000gn/T/, which indeed is the parent of the (ever changing) cache dir. What's puzzling is why matplotlib in one case uses this and in the other case, uses the standard cache dir. Could the pyinstaller build be picking up a different version of matplotlib, or is this an env var issue? Or something else peculiar to pyinstaller?

FWIW, I'm running on Mac OS 10.10.5 (Yosemite) and python 2.7.11 via Anaconda.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?